# Solve for $~f(f(100))~$ when the function is given as

Tags: functions

$$f(x)= ([\{x\}] + 3 - x^7)^{1/7}~.$$

I know that $~[\{x\}]~$ will result in $0$, but I am not able to solve further. Also the answer is extremely simplified and is probably $100$ or some other whole number. So complex answers which require a calculator to be solved won’t work. This problem doesn’t require a calculator, and can be compared to simple identities (eg. $\sin^2x + \cos^2x = 1$).

Comment: These are not my homework questions. Also I am new here, so please hear with. And how do I show you my effort? I do not need to tell you that I was nearly in tears when I couldn’t solve this question, but the rest of the class could

Comment: I could understand, edit your question https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3298619/edit  and add what you know and what you've tried.

Comment: Is $[x]$ supposed to be the integer part of $x$?  If so, in the first iteration it will be $100$, not $0$.  You should be able just to put this in your calculator.  First find $f(100)$, then find $f(that)$

Comment: If $[\{x\}]$ is indeed intended to mean the integer part of the fractional part, then you always get $0$ and thus can completely remove this term, so that $f(x)=-(x^2-3)^{1/7}$. Could you add to your question what you tried, so we can see that our interpretation of "solve" matches what you intended to do?

Comment: I reached the part exactly as u pointed out, but couldn’t get any further. I am fairly confident it’s some sort of an identity, which simplifies the problem to a great extent. I know there is an identity(or whatever it’s called), but I just can’t figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Luca Bresson for pointing out the obvious.

The question as you asked it can't be correct with the story you have told in the comments.

I imagine you had a typo and the question was:

$f(x) = ([\{x\}] + 3 - x^7)^{\frac 17}$.

If so....

As you note $[\{x\}] = 0$ always.

So $f(100) = ([\{100\}] + 3 - 100^7)^{\frac 17} = \color{blue}{(3-100^7)^{\frac 17}}$.

Ad so $f(f(100)) =([\{f(100)\}] + 3 - f(100)^7)^{\frac 17}=$

$(3 - (\color{blue}{(3-100^7)^{\frac 17}})^7)^{\frac 17} =$

$(3 - \color{blue}{(3-100^7)}^1)^{\frac 17} = $

$(3 - \color{blue}{(3-100^7)})^{\frac 17} =$

$(\color{blue}{100^7})^{\frac 17} = \color{blue}{100}^1 = \color{blue}{100}$.

Indeed it will always be the case that

$f(f(K)) = K$.

$f(f(K)) = (3 - f(K)^7)^{\frac 17} =$

$(3 - ((3 - K^7)^{\frac 17})^7)^{\frac 17} =$

$(3 - (3 -K^7))^{\frac 17} =$

$(K^7)^{\frac 17} = K$.

......

Furthermore we use the notation $f^{\underline m}(K)$ to mean $\underbrace {f(f(f(.....(f}_{m\text{ times}}(K))....)))$ then we will have $f^{\underline{2k}}(K) = K$ and $f^{\underline{2k + 1}}(K) = f(K)$.  $f(K)= (3 - K^7)^{\frac 17}$ can be nasty and if $K$ is a positive whole number it can be a negative number with lots of decimals.  But iterating it an even number of times will always "undo" it.

Comment: The answer is wrong. It needs to be simplified even more. I could have done that too, but the answer is probably 100.

Comment: "It needs to be simplified even more." Says who?  Plug it into a calulator and you get $\approx -1.4065924414858160156599286946525....$ but to express it $(3- 9997^{\frac 27})^{\frac 17}$ is as simplified as you can get.  Were you expected to approximate without calculators or something?

Comment: It can solved without a calculator. The answer is in whole numbers. I remember seeing my friend solve it, and it’s a 3-4 step process, with no complex and fancy math involved

Comment: "The answer is in whole numbers."  that's obviously not true. Did you write down the problem right?  Is it $x^2$ and not $x^7$.  is it $()^{\frac 17}$ and not $()^{\frac 12}$.  And are you supposed to do a fractional/integer part somewhere else.  ... MAYBE it's suppos to be $[ [\{x\}] + 3 - x^2]^{\frac 17}$ or something like that  or $[([\{x\}] +3-x^2)^{\frac 17}]$.

Comment: And how do you know your friend did it right?  Maybe he/she did a foolish mistake.

Comment: I know he is right, cause the answer key verified it. And the teacher applauded him as he was able to solve such a difficult question.

Comment: Well, I can't help you unless you give me the question correctly typed.  I answered the question that you asked.  But the story you tell of your friend, teacher and answer key, just can't work with the question you asked.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but long story short, your answer is wrong. (I don’t mean to be rude)

Comment: If $f(x) = ([\{ x \}] + 3 - x^{\color{red} 7})^{1/7}$, then $f(f(100)) = 100$.

Comment: No.  Long story short your *question* is wrong.  And Luca Bressan has the obvious right question.  If you replace the $x^2$ with $x^7$ then  ... it *is* very easy and in just a few lines.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(100)=([\{100\}] + 3 -10000)^{\frac17}=(-9997)^{\frac17}\approx-3.72743 $$

$$f(f(100))=([\{-3.72743\}]+3-(-3.72743)^2)^{\frac17}=([0.27257]+3-13.89276529)^{\frac17}\approx-1.4065740$$

Comment: +1 for doing what was asked straightforwardly.  Even though what was asked was the wrong question.